# unnest'ing a variable in a tibble that is made up of nested lists

Tags: r, dplyr

Working with some JSON data, I have a tibble with a strange structure:

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
df <- data_frame(y = c("D", "E"), z = list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, c = 5)))
```

I want to unnest z. This almost works:

```
> unnest(df, z, .id = "name")
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  y     z          name
  <chr> <list>    <int>
1 D     <dbl [1]>     1
2 D     <dbl [1]>     1
3 D     <dbl [1]>     1
4 E     <dbl [1]>     2
5 E     <dbl [1]>     2
```

But what I want is something like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  y         z name 
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 D         1 a    
2 D         2 b    
3 D         3 c    
4 E         4 a    
5 E         5 c
```

How can I avoid losing the name information and pop out the values for z?

Thanks to @AntoniosK for solving my problem. Here is his (slightly edited) solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(d = map(z, ~data.frame(.x) %>% gather(name, z))) %>%
  unnest(d)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   y     name      z
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 D     a         1
# 2 D     b         2
# 3 D     c         3
# 4 E     a         4
# 5 E     c         5
```

Comment: Are you able to get the list of lists as its own object? Something like `x <- list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, c = 5))`? If so, you can do `data_frame(x=unlist(x), name=names(x))` to get the desired output. But I don't know if that solves your underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I have edited the question to make more clear that the original tibble has other columns that I need to maintain. I am happy to manipulate x if that is helpful.

Comment: How are you going from name as a numeric column to name as letters? I'm missing the pattern

Comment: unnest() is doing that to me, much to my chagrin. That is the behavior that I seek to avoid/change. I am not even exactly sure why/how unnest() does this.

Answer (score 3):

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))

df <- data_frame(y = c("D", "E"), x = list(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, c = 5)))

df %>%
  mutate(d = map(x, ~data.frame(.x) %>% gather(name, x))) %>%
  unnest(d)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   y     name      x
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 D     a         1
# 2 D     b         2
# 3 D     c         3
# 4 E     a         4
# 5 E     c         5
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment! This does, indeed, solve the question as I posed it originally. But, I should have made more clear that there was other information in that data frame that I want to keep around. I have edited the original question to make that more clear. Is there a way to use your approach in this situation?

Comment: @user2933846 I've just updated my answer. Hope you'll be able to generalise it to your real problem :)

Comment: Works great. Thanks! One note for other readers is that, by using "x" as my variable name in the example, I make this (correct) answer more difficult to parse than it ought to be. ".x" within ~data.frame(.x) has nothing to do with my variable x. You need to keep that as is, even as you change the other two occurrences of x to be your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AntoniosK for solving my problem. Here is his (slightly edited) solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(d = map(z, ~data.frame(.x) %>% gather(name, z))) %>%
  unnest(d)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   y     name      z
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 D     a         1
# 2 D     b         2
# 3 D     c         3
# 4 E     a         4
# 5 E     c         5
```